# How to send a correct status header with Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I read about Wordpress' own `status_header()` function and I read on PHPs own functions to output a status header. I want to output a 410 gone header on a particular page. But if I try and check the header I only get '200' OK.

I tried for example:

```
<?php if( is_page( 97324 )) { http_response_code( 410 ); } ?>
```

As a solution for PHP newer as version 5.4.

And I tried Wordpress' own `status_header` as follows:

```
<?php if( is_page( 97324 )) { status_header( 410 ); } ?>
```

I put that line in the header template at the very top, as I read this ist where it should be put.

---

### Solution

I added a working solution according to the answer I was given by @jimmy obonyo. I used the action hook `pre_get_posts` and now my page sends the correct status code. My solution looks like this and this code is put to the theme's `functions.php`

```
function handle_410() {
    if( is_page( 97324 )) { 
        status_header( 410 );
        nocache_headers();
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'handle_410' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `status_header()` before `$wp_query->set`  in the function file :

```
function handle_404() {

    // Guess it's time to 404.
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();

}
```

Comment: Thx a lot. You pointed me in the right direction. I added my working solution in an edit of my question. I had to look for the right action hook but now it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made multiple attempts, but what ultimately resolved the issue was adding an exit statement to terminate the function at that point, as the following code snippet:

```
function any(){
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Something went wrong.'));
    exit;
}
```